# OKVideo two videos in one page differect sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, parallax, okvideo

Ok so I've done alot of digging and can't find any info on this. I'm trying to get the jquery plugin OkVideo to make 2 "section" tags have a different video in each however even if i rename the container to be specifically ID'd the video loads in one container.

e.g.

```
<section>
    <div id="container1"></div>
</section>
<section>
    <div id="container2"></div>
</section>
```

```js
$('#container1').okvideo({
    source: 'Video1 Url',
    volume: 0,
    loop: true,
    hd: false,
    adproof: true,
    annotations: false
});
$('#container2').okvideo({
    source: 'Video2 URL',
    volume: 0,
    loop: true,
    hd: false,
    adproof: true,
    annotations: false
});
```

Now the above is causing the 2nd video to overwrite the first video in it's container. Which is not the desired effect. Can someone suggest a similar plugin that allows this or an overwrite to get this to work without recoding half of the plugin javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so after a few hours of fighting I finally fixed this by rejigging the okfocus okvideo to take an extra option "newtarget" which identified if there where multiple videos on the page.

```
if (base.options.newtarget == undefined) {
     base.options.newtarget = "";
}

var target = $("#" + base.options.newtarget) || base.options.target || $('body');
var position = target[0] == $('body')[0] ? 'fixed' : 'absolute';
```

All items being added to the page had the newtarget appended to the id e.g.

```
target.append('<div id="okplayer' + base.options.newtarget + '" style="pos.....
```

Then we add the options to the window data setting each option setting to take the newtarget as part of its naming convention(please ensure to format it in lowercase and strip extra '-' etc.)

```
$(window).data('okoptions' + options.newtarget.replace('-', '').toLowerCase(), base.options);
```

Then locate the function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() or if vimeo's vimeoPlayerReady() and extended it with a class selector for the videos on the page

```
 $(".videoClass").each(function(e) {
 options = jQuery(window).data('okoptions' + $(this).attr('id').replace('-', ''));....
```

once these have been added you add an unobtrusive function to add all the options

```
 var collection = $(".videoClass");
 collection.each(function () {
 $("#" + $(this).attr('id')).okvideo({
        source: $(this).attr("data-link"),
        volume: 0,
        loop: true,
        hd: false,
        adproof: true,
        annotations: false,
        newtarget: $(this).attr('id')
        });
 });
```

This could probably be neatened up but as I was in a rush the is this working solution.

Comment: Hey, do you have a URL of the whole thing in place?

Comment: I do have a URL unfortunately I can't share it this time :( We all know the drill :P

Comment: OK that is fine, can you post your full okvideo.js file then and a snippet of your code? I did your changed but was not able to get it working.  Rather than reinvent the wheel...  would be nice to see how you did it.. even just the changed portions would be great?

Comment: can you post your modified okvideo.js code?  Or a fiddle with 2 videos working same times?  Please man! I can't get your code to work.  I dont know what I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few hours working on this. This selected solution wasnt very helpful so I have a working, but certainly less than ideal solution. My goal was to have two fullscreen background videos when navigating with jquery.fullPage.js.

OKVideo injects html to enable the video, I grabbed this html for my first video and changed the youtube url, used jquery append to insert the new html video code into proper code section.

One problem I had was that the video didnt repeat properly - but I used jquery to fadeOut the video id once it was concluded. Im sure if you wanted it to repeat you could simply put the code into a js loop.

Here is the code I needed to 'append':

replace the sample video id "HkMNOlYcpHg" with your youtube video id, and replace example.com with your web domain.

```
   jQuery('#section3').append('<div id="okplayer-mask1" style="position: 
absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: -998; height: 100%; 
width: 100%; background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPABAP
///wAAACH5BAEKAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw%3D%3D);"></div><iframe id="okplayer1" 
style="position:absolute;left:-10%;top:-10%;overflow:hidden;z-index:-999;
height:120%;width:120%;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video 
player" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed
/HkMNOlYcpHg?autohide=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;cc_load_policy=0&amp;controls=3&
amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;fs=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F
%2Fexample.com&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;loop=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&
amp;wmode=opaque&amp;hd=1"></iframe>');
```